# Sequence of shortcuts not working when holding down CTRL

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 21.04, 21.10

I somehow miss-configured Ubuntu and I don't know what I did, this is what happened.

**The problem:** Only the first shortcut in a sequence of Ctrl-left shortcuts is executed, when the Ctrl key is kept pressed.

We frequently use series of shortcuts, for example when browsing we copy some text in the current page, open a new tab and paste in the search bar. This would require the following combination: Ctrl+C, Ctrl+T, Ctrl-V. However, when you combine those you naturally keep Ctrl pressed resulting in this sequence: [Ctrl pressed]-C+T+V.

In my current configuration, only the first Copy would have worked in this sequence.

However, if I release the Ctrl key and repress it then the next command works again (that's not always possible, for example, when cycling through chrome tabs).

I am using Ubuntu 21.10, and I made the following modifications:

- Using Tweaks I switched Left alt and Left Ctrl
- I updated the Alt Tab behavior to make use of Super key. i.e. Super+Tab
- (Most likely not important) I configured my terminal (Terminator) to use CTRL+C for copying instead of interrupting the command

Everything was working good, until I started to notice this issue (however I was making other modifications that I didn't keep track of but afaik not related to shortcuts or the keyboard)

Does anyone know what could be the root cause?

(btw, I tried disabling the above changes etc.)

Ubuntu version 21.10, X11, GNOME

Answer (score 0):

You may have configured your Gnome to show the location of the pointer when Ctrl is pressed. That interferes with some shortcuts.

To disable that option, go to *Tweaks* -> *Keyboard & Mouse* -> *Pointer Location*.

I saw similar problems as you describe, which were solved by this setting.

Comment: It seems that this is related to it. After disabling the Pointer location CTRL stopped working in any combination, do you know why that could be the case?

Comment: Indeed, check all of your accessibility settings. Sounds like if the issue may be there. One option there indeed allows that e.g. Ctrl+C is ontained by hitting Ctrl first, then c.

Comment: @vanadium I am not able to find that option under accessibility settings checked normal settings (and tweaks)

Comment: I wonder if *sticky keys* is enabled? See https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-stickykeys.html.en for information.

Comment: Type Assist (AccessX) is disabled in my settings

Comment: I notice a type of behavior in the command line but not anywhere else:

I run `cat` in terminal, and then when I execute e.g. ctrl+a the first time I get ^A but the subsequent times it is dimming.

Comment: @Rinor - Did you reboot after changing this setting?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio yes I did, just tried that again, but the hotkeys don't work even after disabling the pointer location and rebooting the laptop

Comment: I am thinking to reinstall ubuntu and see if it gets fixed